# iOS App distribution is failed to AppStore with error : Invalid MinimumOSVersion

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

ERROR: Asset validation failed (90066) Invalid MinimumOSVersion. The value for the Info.plist key MinimumOSVersion could not be parsed . (ID: 37cd46e6-0921-413a-acec-9bbe461338d0)
I'm already set the minimum version(11.0) in everywhere(Also the Podfile platform :ios, '11.0').
By the way,my xcode is 14.0.1, flutter is 3.3.4.

[Minimum Deployments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYCDi.png)

[AppFrameworkInfo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvrFz.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have sloved. If you have the same question,you can try to delete following code in the Podfile.
'''
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0',
'''

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As it happens in Firebase, issues with the package caused this failure. In this case, Google released a fix (10.22.1) that directly resolves.
https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios